# What steps are required to mitigate the CVE-2021-44521 exploit in Cassandra UDFs?

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra operators are concerned that they are vulnerable to the exploit identified in CVE-2021-44521.

What steps can operators take to mitigate the risk and exposure to the vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

An attacker can exploit the vulnerability described in [CVE-2021-44521](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44521) if scripted **user-defined functions** (UDFs) are enabled on a node in `cassandra.yaml` (disabled by default):

```
enable_user_defined_functions: true
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: true
```

and UDF threads is disabled (default is true):

```
enable_user_defined_functions_threads: false
```

### Risk

A cluster is not vulnerable to the exploit under the following conditions:

- UDFs are disabled (default configuration).
- UDFs are enabled and UDF threads is enabled by default.

For a cluster to be vulnerable, an administrator has chosen to disable UDF threads against recommendation and it is not safe to do so.

An attacker requires permissions to create user-defined functions and nodes are particularly vulnerable if authentication is not enabled on the cluster:

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
```

It is possible for an attacker to create functions that can execute arbitrary code on a node with this exploit.

### Workaround

Disabling UDF threads is insecure and not recommended since it effectively disables the security manager in Java.

Re-enable UDF threads in `cassandra.yaml` and restart each node in the cluster for the change to take effect:

```
enable_user_defined_functions_threads: true
```

### Solution

CVE-2021-44521 has been patched in Apache Cassandra 3.0.26, 3.11.12 and 4.0.2 ([CASSANDRA-17352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17352)).

If an administrator wants to run user-defined functions without threads (NOT recommended) on patched clusters, an administrator will need to explicitly allow insecure UDFs with:

```
allow_insecure_udfs: true
```

in `cassandra.yaml`. If existing UDFs require access to `java.lang.System` (NOT recommended), set:

```
allow_extra_insecure_udfs: true
```

Note that it is not necessary to upgrade if UDF threads is enabled (default) on a cluster.